# Cannot retrieve channel.xml for channel "pecl.php.net" (Connection to `ssl://pecl.php.net:443' failed: Operation timed out)

Tags: php, pecl

From today 2022-08-11, the `pecl channel-update pecl.php.net` command is not working.

It start working and after a few seconds returns an error `Cannot retrieve channel.xml for channel "pecl.php.net" (Connection to ssl://pecl.php.net:443 failed: Operation timed out)`.

Here's the entire message:

```
$ pecl channel-update pecl.php.net

Updating channel "pecl.php.net"
Channel "pecl.php.net" is not responding over http://, failed with message: File http://pecl.php.net:80/channel.xml not valid (redirected but no location)
Trying channel "pecl.php.net" over https:// instead
Cannot retrieve channel.xml for channel "pecl.php.net" (Connection to `ssl://pecl.php.net:443' failed: Operation timed out)
```

I tried it from my local computer and in a GitLab pipeline that use to work well, until today.

Does anybody knows what happens?
Anything changed today 2022-08-11 ?

Comment: Seeing the same thing, when building a docker container and installing Imagick or Redis... It has worked intermittently, but mostly fails after a long wait. Let me know if you find out why, or find a workaround! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

pecl.php.net has been intermittently down for several hours, not sure if they are being ddos'd or what the deal is, but certainly making it a challenge to complete certain builds right now. They'll get it squared away I'm sure, but tough to patient in the interim.

Answer (score 0):

pecl.php.net is up again now !
But, to avoid situations like today. I switched to build from source instead of using pecl

Comment: How you did that?  for example I need to update pecl and the install runkit7, xdebug and yaml, like this:
```
pecl channel-update pecl.php.net ; 
pecl install runkit7-alpha ; 
pecl install xdebug-2.9.8 ; 
pecl install yaml ; 
```